# Criar alias para imports de css

Tags: css, typescript, webpack

Tenho um projeto react que usa typescript e gostaria de ter alguma forma de importar css sem colocar o caminho todo do local do css.

Gostaria de evitar esse tempo de import:

`@import '../../../../shared/assets/src/assets/fonts/fonts.css'`

Comment: veja se esse conteudo possa te ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502855/vite-import-css-with-alias-in-main-ts

Answer (score 0):

[Esse pacote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) resolve isso, usa do `package.json` para configurar os alias pra qualquer pasta.